# Pagination on Django Rest Framework when the data does not come from a model from the database

Tags: django-rest-framework, pagination

I'm trying to create an endpoint who returns the values from an Enum, but I need to make it with pagination because the UI library we use was designed to received exactly the same format that Django Rest Framework return when we read from a database.

The problem is that I cannot make the pagination to work. No matter which base class I use (ApiView, ListView, etc), the Response return doesn't has the ***count***, ***next***, ***previous*** and ***results*** fields (in ***results*** is where the real json should be).

I tried to overwrite pagination with `pagination_class` on the view class, and also creating a custom pagination class based on `PageNumberPagination`, but nothing.

Also, I tried to create a custom `get_paginated_response` method on my custom pagination class, but when I debug it looks like the method is not called.

What I'm doing wrong? I imagine it should be a way to tell DRF "take this data, even if is not from a model, and return that as a paginated list of fields"

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me in the past, I just called `paginate_queryset` with the enum and the `request`. Then, you need to return the response of `get_paginated_response(page)`. So, something like this:

```py
class SampleViewSet(views.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        values = [e.value for e in MyEnum]
        paginator = YourPaginationClass()
        page = paginator.paginate_queryset(values, request)
        if page is not None:
            return paginator.get_paginated_response(page)

        return Response(data)
```